# Transformar um objeto em um array

Tags: javascript

Tenho o retorno de um objeto assim:

```
response = {
    1: "Julio",
    2: "Rubens",
    3: "Narciso",
    4: "Elton",
    5: "Junior"
}
```

e gostaria de criar um array com todos os nomes, ex:

```
array = ["Julio", "Rubens", "Narciso", "Elton", "Junior"]
```

Obs: As vezes retorna mais nomes ou menos.

Comment: Como assim "As vezes retorna mais nomes ou menos"? Poderia [edit] a pergunta com o código? - de qq forma, tentou com `Object.values(response)`?

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma bem básica é fazendo um loop no objeto para popular um array:

```js
const response = {
    1: "Julio",
    2: "Rubens",
    3: "Narciso",
    4: "Elton",
    5: "Junior"
}

const array = [];

for (const key in response)
  array.push(response[key]);

console.log(array);
```

Mas há um método nativo que faz isso pra você, o [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values):

```js
const response = {
    1: "Julio",
    2: "Rubens",
    3: "Narciso",
    4: "Elton",
    5: "Junior"
}

const array = Object.values(response);

console.log(array);
```

Você pode ver a compatibilidade dele no [Can I use](https://caniuse.com/object-values)